# Work visa refusal at German embassy in Islamabad, Pakistan

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

Due to the lack availability of long-term visa in Islamabad, I took an appointment for a short-term visit visa. During the interview they asked me why I did not apply for a long-term visa. I told them no appointment was available for long-term visas. She took my documents and after a week they sent me my passport, stating objection no 8 and 9. The documents were attached. Kindly inform me how I may now apply for appeal.

Comment: How can you appeal when it is your fault that you deliberately applied for the wrong type of visa? If there are no long term visa appointments that's bad luck for you, but does not mean you can use a short term appointment instead.

Comment: This site is for short term travel, like vacations. We have a whole other site for living and working in other countries, called [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to appeal, as the decision seems to be correct. You applied for a short-term visa to work in Germany, and they determined that you are unlikely to leave the country before the short-term visa expires (reason 9). They may think so because it appears as if you told them so (as you said that you wanted to work in Germany). So the refusal appears to be correct, and hence, an appeal will not get you anywhere.

Make a fresh application/appointment for the right type of visa.